# getting the data on same browser window on click of row using primefaces or jsf

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

i am new on prime faces .I have a user with some attribute  i have  shown the table of user data . Now the requirement is that, on click of particular user row  the data associated with that user must be shown on same window under the table please tell the way to do this i m trying to use layout but the problem is how i can get the data on same window .Give me learing site link if possible doing the same thing or tell me the procedure thanks

```
package com.poc.faces;
import java.util.Collection;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent;
import org.primefaces.event.UnselectEvent;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class UserManagedBean {
    UserService service = new UserService();

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String searchUser;
    private Collection<User> searchUsersResults;
    private User selectedUser;

    public UserService getService() {
        return service;
    }

    public void setService(UserService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getSearchUser() {
        return searchUser;
    }

    public void setSearchUser(String searchUser) {
        this.searchUser = searchUser;
    }

    public Collection<User> getSearchUsersResults() {
        return searchUsersResults = service.getAllUser();
    }

    public void setSearchUsersResults(Collection<User> searchUsersResults) {
        this.searchUsersResults = searchUsersResults;
    }

    public User getSelectedUser() {
        return selectedUser;
    }

    public String login() {

        if ("sas".equalsIgnoreCase(getUsername())
                && "sas".equals(getPassword())) {
            return "home";
        } else {

            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

            context.addMessage("username", new FacesMessage(
                    "Invalid UserName and Password"));

            return "login";

        }
    }



    public void setSelectedUser(User selectedUser) {
        this.selectedUser = selectedUser;
    }

    public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("User Selected",
                ((User) event.getObject()).getUsername());

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    }

    public void onRowUnselect(UnselectEvent event) {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Car Unselected",
                ((User) event.getObject()).getUsername());

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    }
}
```

This home.xhtml

where i am getting the tabledata

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<h:head>
    <link href="../css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <p:layout style="min-width:400px;min-height:200px;" id="layout">
        <p:layoutUnit position="center">
            <h:form prependId="false">
                <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="left_column"
                    style="width: 2px; left: 2px; margin-left: 2px">
                    <center>
                        <H1>UserData</H1>
                        <br />

                        <p:dataTable value="#{userManagedBean.searchUsersResults}"
                            var="user" pagination="true" rows="5" styleClass="userTable"
                            headerClass="userTableHeader"
                            rowClasses="userTableOddRow,userTableEvenRow"
                            paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                            rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15">
                            <!-- <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{userManagedBean.onRowSelect}"
                        update=":form:display :form:growl" oncomplete="carDialog.show()" />
                    <p:ajax event="rowUnselect"
                        listener="#{userManagedBean.onRowUnselect}" update=":form:growl" /> -->


                            <p:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">UserId</f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{user.userId}"></h:outputText>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">Username</f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{user.username}"></h:outputText>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">EmailId</f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value=" #{user.emailId}"></h:outputText>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">Phone</f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value=" #{user.phone}"></h:outputText>
                            </p:column>
                        </p:dataTable>
                    </center>
                </h:panelGroup>
            </h:form>

            <p:layoutUnit position="west" resizable="true" size="100"
                minSize="40" maxSize="200">  
        West  
        </p:layoutUnit>
    </p:layout>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is a component of PF called layoutUnit. are you sure it's not layout?

Comment: yes there is layout unit component in prime faces http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/layoutFull.jsf this is the link can u please tell me the another way to do the task